# Как изменить запрос к БД с учетом условия логического И (&)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Что нужно изменить, что бы в выборку не добавлялись строки в которых `COLUMN_REP` и `COLUMN_CONS` содержат `null`?

Вот сам запрос

```
    public Cursor get_data_for_cons_rep_graph()
{
    return refillDB.query(DB_TABLE,
            new String[] {COLUMN_REP, COLUMN_CONS, COLUMN_DATE_FOR_SORTING},
            null, null,
            null, null,
            COLUMN_DATE_FOR_SORTING + " ASC");
}
```

Я использовал такое условие для ограничения выборки (в другом запросе)

```
COLUMN_F + " NOT LIKE ?",
            new String[] {"null"},
```

но это условие для одной колонки, а как сделать с условием `И` для двух колонок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
    public Cursor get_data_for_cons_rep_graph()
{

String selection = COLUMN_REP+ " != " + null
                    +" AND " + COLUMN_CONS+ " != " + null;

    return refillDB.query(DB_TABLE,
            new String[] {COLUMN_REP, COLUMN_CONS, COLUMN_DATE_FOR_SORTING},
            selection, 
            null,
            null, 
            null,
            COLUMN_DATE_FOR_SORTING + " ASC");
}
```

Comment: @Howling: пожалуйста. Поправил ответ.